# nginx won't use 100% cpu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

i'm just benchmarking a default install of nginx trying to get it to serve as many requests per second as possible. i expected it to use 100% cpu under load like other webservers do, but i can't get it to use more than about 40%.

i tried on Ubuntu and Manjaro with the same results.

`ab -k -c 500 -n 1000000 http://localhost/` is getting about 150,000 requests per second. i imagine it could serve at least twice as much if it used the full cpus but i can't figure out how. it's just serving the default nginx html page. is this normal? what could be blocking it?

i've made sure to use these settings:

```
access_log off;
worker_processes auto;
worker_connections 1024;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
gzip on;
expires 365d;
```

Comment: Have you considered the resources consumed by the client (`ab`) and any other bottlenecks (e.g. network IO)?

Comment: total system cpu usage isn't going above 40%. i tried a different webserver and it went to 100% (it was serving less req/s though). it's localhost so network IO shouldn't matter?

Comment: Network performance still matters even for localhost. There are layer 3 packets even if there is no layer 2 frames.   Measure exactly the functions CPU time is being spent to get an idea of where the bottlenecks might be.  For example, run `perf top`